# Apply PageCurl animation in ViewPager with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, page-curl

I have a ViewPager with multiple fragments and I would like to add the PageCurl effect when a fragment is swiped.
Like this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVZHN_o45sg).

I've managed to do it using Bitmaps, but not with fragments.
How can I implement such a thing with fragments?